# Ordinary ANOVA or Repeated Measurements ANOVA

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

My experiment consists in testing the effect of a compound on a cell line. I have 5 groups: control, concentration 1, 2, 3 and 4 of the compound. I performed three replicates of the experiment, each using cells from a different flask and cell passage, but still from the same original vial. In the same replicate, cells in the different experimental wells are coming from the same flask. To perform the analysis, considering that my values are normally distributed, should I use the ordinary ANOVA or the repeated measurements ANOVA? My supervisor said that we should use the second option since cells are coming from the same flask and cell vial so they can be considered as the same "subject". But I am confused since at the end the cells are plated, treated and measured in different wells, so it is not really as the same cells undergo the different treatments. It would be very helpful to know your opinion, thanks a lot in advance! :)